# Training neural network in IBM Load Sharing Facility (LSF)

Tags: python, neural-network, lsf

I was granted an access to some high-performance computing system to conduct some experiments with machine learning.

This system has an IBM's LSF 10.1 installed.
I was instructed to run `bsub` command to submit a new ML task to a queue.

I use Python+Keras+Tensorflow for my tasks.

My typical workflow is following. I define NN architecture and training parameters in a python script, `train.py`, commit it to git repo, then run it.
Then I make some changes in `train.py`, commit it and run again.

I've developed following `bsub` script

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
#BSUB -P "project"
#BSUB -q queue
#BSUB -n 1
#BSUB -o %J.log
#BSUB -e %J.err
#BSUB -cwd "/home/user/my_project/nntrain"

module load cuda9.0 cudnn_v7 nccl_2.1.15
source /home/user/my_python/bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/my_project/lib

python train.py 2>&1 | tee ${LSB_JOBID}_out.log
```

Now the question.

I've defined a network, then have run `bsub  < batch_submit`.
The job is put in a queue and is assigned some identifier, say 12345678.

While it is not running, waiting for a next free node, I make some changes to `train.py` to create a new variant and submit it again in a similar manner: `bsub  < batch_submit`

Let the new job ID be 12345692. The job 12345678 is still waiting.

Now I've got two jobs, waiting for their nodes.

What about the script train.py?

Will it be the same for both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will. When you submit the job, `bsub` will look only at the first few lines starting with `#BSUB` in order to determine what resources are required by your job, and on which node(s) to run it best.

All the other parts of the script, which do not start with `#BSUB`, are interpreted only when the script stops `pending` and starts `running`. In one particular line, `bash` will encounter the command `python train.py`, load the current version of `train.py`, and execute it.

That is, `bsub` does not "freeze" the environment in any way; when the job starts running, it will run the latest version of `train.py`. If you submit two jobs that both refer to the same `.py`-file, they both will run the same python script (the latest version).

In case you're wondering how to run thousand jobs with thousand different settings, here is what I usually do:

1. Make sure that your `.py` script can either accept command line arguments with configuration parameters, or that it can get configuration from some file; Do not rely on manual modification of the script to change some settings.
2. Create a bsub-template file that looks approximately like your bash script above, but leaves at least one meta-variable which can specify the parameters of the experiment. By "meta-variable" I mean a unique string that doesn't collide with anything else in your bash script, for example `NAME_OF_THE_DATASET`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # 
   #BSUB -P "project"
   #BSUB -q queue
   #BSUB -n 1
   #BSUB -o %J.log
   #BSUB -e %J.err
   #BSUB -cwd "/home/user/project/nntrain"

   module load cuda9.0 cudnn_v7 nccl_2.1.15
   source /home/user/my_python/bin/activate
   export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/my_project/lib

   python train.py NAME_OF_THE_DATASET 2>&1 | tee ${LSB_JOBID}_out.log
   ```
3. Create a separate bash-script with a loop that plugs in different values for the metavariable (e.g. by replacing `NAME_OF_THE_DATASET` by `myDataset1.csv`, ... , `myDatasetN.csv` using `sed`), and then submits the modified template by `bsub`.

It might be not the simplest solution (one probably can get away with simpler numbering schemes using the facilities of `bsub` itself), but I found it to be very flexible, because it works equally well with multiple meta-variables and all kind of flags and settings, and it also lets you insert different preprocessing scripts into the `bsub` template.

Comment: My solution is to add `__main__.py` that runs training, zip all related files into an archive file with unique name, then run `python archive.zip`. More details here: https://gist.github.com/rochacbruno/ed19c5d9ba9bb50391a2

Comment: @wl2776 I can't quite follow, what does it have to do with the above answer? What if your program is not in python, and what if you don't want to put "all related files" into a single archive, because you want to run different programs with different combinations of datasets and parameters, without having to copy every possible combination of parameters into an archive? Copying all related files for each run doesn't scale, because it leads to exponential blowup when the number of inputs and parameters grows.

Comment: It was inspired by your answer, thanks for it. My data set changes very rarely; my model is split in 3 files: load_data, define_model, run_optimizer; and I'd like to store history of NN hyperparameter search in git: one commit - one parameter set. If I would want run different programs with different parameters, then I would use templates and sed. Ah! Now I can do a grid search in this way.